# Exit Ubuntu Splash Screen

Tags: boot, grub2

Is there a way to exit the splash screen during boot and view the verbose boot without rebooting?

For future viewers sake: this is for GRUB2 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use grub2 then the following should do the trick for every installed kernel on every boot:

- make a backup copy of `/etc/default/grub`
- Open up `/etc/default/grub` as root
- Change the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""` (if there is more than only `quiet` and `splash` between the quotes, keep it!)
- save the changes
- run `sudo update-grub`
- reboot

This way this change will even be permanent after a kernel update. Also this is the only way that works in grub2 since `boot/grub/menu.lst` was in grub1 and is not used anymore in grub2.

More about configuring grub2 in ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

Comment: If there is anything else except the words **quiet splash** it should be kept. So, just delete **quiet splash**.

Comment: Of course you are right. I have edited your comment right into the answer.

Answer (score 5):

On bootup, press <kbd>F2</kbd>.

Now, you'll have the verbose feedback mode.

Comment: Doing this only shows the verbose text once. You will have to do it on every reboot.

Comment: @MaxMackie however, if you only need it once, then it's great. Also has the advantage that you don't have to edit your GRUB. Messing with a bootloader like that is a *little* hairy sometimes, even if you know what you're doing.

Comment: At what point? Like just before the splash screen?

Comment: @stuartc At any point during bootup, before the display manager starts.

Answer (score 1):

This works only for grub versions prior than grub2!

Open `/boot/grub/menu.lst`. You'll see a block like this:

```
title xxx
root (hd0,0)
kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.22-14-generic root=UUID=xxxx ro quiet splash
initrd /boot/initrd.img-2.6.22-14-generic
quiet
```

Change it to:

```
title xxx
root (hd0,0)
kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.22-14-generic root=UUID=xxxx ro
initrd /boot/initrd.img-2.6.22-14-generic
```

Note that the kernel version numbers in your case may be different. Save the file and the splash screen should be replaced with a verbose boot from now on.

Comment: I had a poke around, I'm afraid Ubuntu is using GRUB2 in recent versions, and `menu.lst` has been replaced by `grub.cfg` which is autogenerated by a pile of scripts.. :/