# 12.04 Boot-up loop

Tags: usb, modprobe

Whenever most Linux OS tries to boot up, they loop on modprobe and/or when finding my USB Keyboard and Mouse(both Logitech).

Ubuntu 10.04 works perfectly(and *Mandriva*), but any higher than 10.04, or any other Linux OS won't even go into Live mode, or install. (On Linux Mint 12, boot-up gets terminated on signal 9, then it loops on my 2 USB devices.)

I've recently had **Some**, and **Most** luck with 12.04.

I tried a CD, and LiveUSB and get the same issue, while booting up into Live mode, and after Live mode is on(I know it is running because it responds to my keystrokes), I just get the "_" blinking in the top left corner. 
(Reason I know the ISO, CD, and USB are all good, I booted my Acer Netbook up with them.)

I've never had any of these issues until I got my new computer.

Is there an incompatibility with Unix going on here?

Board: Asus P8H61-M LE/CSM 
Processor: i5 2500
GPU: EVGA GTX 460

Any help would be greatly appreciated .

Edit 1: I've asked on a bunch of different support forums, and getting no where. :/

Answer (score 0):

To see the boot log, [press F2 during boot](https://askubuntu.com/a/87811/42522) or remove the `quiet` and `splash` options from your grub menu entry, and maybe `vt.handoff=7` from `/etc/grub.d/10_linux`. [This page](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1768725) mentions a hang on Ubuntu 11 caused by that last option.