# Verbose  booting of kernel

Tags: grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable X at boot time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16371/how-to-disable-x-at-boot-time)
>   [Exit Ubuntu Splash Screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87809/exit-ubuntu-splash-screen)

Here I have the file: `/etc/defaults/grub`

What do I need to put in that file to make the booting more verbose. I want to see all messages of the kernel while it is loading

Comment: You are going to find your answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16371/how-to-disable-x-at-boot-time